# Function does not return value when it should

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote the following code for binary search

```
int binarySearch(int input[], int start, int end, int element) {
    
    if(start<=end) { 
        
        int mid = (start+end)/2;

        if(input[mid]==element) {
            cout<<"mid will be returned\n";
            return mid;       
        }

        else if(input[mid]<element) {
            binarySearch(input, mid+1, end, element);
        } else if (input[mid]>element) {
            binarySearch(input, start, mid-1, element);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now, for the input

```
10                    //size of array
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  //array
1                     //element to be found
```

I get the output

```
mid will be returned
-1
```

But if I put an else before `return -1`(in the second last line), it works just fine and returns

```
mid will be returned
0
```

The question is, shouldn't the function just return `mid = 0` in the first case and `return 0`?

Here's the main function for your reference:

```
int main() {
    int input[100000],length,element, ans;
    cin >> length;
    for(int i =0;i<length;i++)
    { 
        cin >> input[i];;
    }

    cin>>element;
    ans = binarySearch(input, 0, length-1,  element);
    cout<< ans << endl;
}
```

Comment: [Turn up your compiler's warning level](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/97xz3WTjj). Putting in the `else` there will cause a compiler with an ample warning level set to issue a warning and save you a whole bunch of time.

Comment: The function calls itself recursively, discards the value returned by any recursive call, and then returns `-1`.    Putting the `else` before the `return -1` causes undefined behaviour due to falling off the end of a non-`void` function  (it then returning `0` is just happenstance, with your particular compiler).

Comment: Just some tipps: 1.) don't write multiple variable declarations in one line, you probably won't have any issues in simple scenarios like this, but as soon as you start initializing them in the same line or have pointers it get's messy; 2.) this is a perfect example for a `std::vector<int>` instead of `int[]` - you're either wasting space or running out of it

Comment: And to elaborate further on the vector point: by using `int input[100000]` you're allocating 400kB (probably) on the stack just for your array. That's nearly half the stack size you have available in some environments. Combining that with a recursive function can easily lead to a stack overflow.

Comment: Your endpoints are inclusive, but you return -1 when `start == end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put a `return` before your recursive calls

```
int binarySearch(int input[], int start, int end, int element) {
    
    if(start<=end) { 
        
        int mid = (start+end)/2;

        if(input[mid]==element) {
            cout<<"mid will be returned\n";
            return mid;       
        }

        else if(input[mid]<element) {
            return binarySearch(input, mid+1, end, element); // here
        } else if (input[mid]>element) {
            return binarySearch(input, start, mid-1, element); // here 
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return on where you calling again the function. Return will return the value to the caller function so each recursive will return the value to its caller function. So your code should be,

```
int binarySearch(int input[], int start, int end, int element) {
    
    if(start<=end) { 
        
        int mid = (start+end)/2;

        if(input[mid]==element) {
            cout<<"mid will be returned\n";
            return mid;       
        }

        else if(input[mid]<element) {
            return binarySearch(input, mid+1, end, element);
        } else if (input[mid]>element) {
            return binarySearch(input, start, mid-1, element);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct except the fact you don't return the result of `binarySearch` in recursive function.

So that gets executed but the result is not used by the original (top level) `binarySearch` call.

To make the main program get the right value of `binarySearch` method, it should call itself each time.

Change this part and try again:

```
else if(input[mid]<element) {
            return binarySearch(input, mid+1, end, element);
        } else if (input[mid]>element) {
            return binarySearch(input, start, mid-1, element);
        }
```